# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0 app crashes in users android phones

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

My app goes live recently on the google play store. I tested it on multiple devices and it works smoothly on all of them. After I launched it, it crashes more frequently.
This is the crashlytic data provided by firebase.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity.setQuestion(QuestionsActivity.java:151)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity.access$100(QuestionsActivity.java:43)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity$1.onComplete(QuestionsActivity.java:105)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(:4)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Here is my java code(relevant areas. I just put "********" to identify it easy in the full script)

- **QuestionsActivity.java:151**

  private void setQuestion()
  {
  timer.setText(String.valueOf(40));

  ```
   question.setText(questionList.get(0).getQuestion()); **//this is 151 line**
   option1.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionA());
   option2.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionB());
   option3.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionC());
   option4.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionD());

   qCount.setText(String.valueOf(1)+"/"+ String.valueOf(questionList.size()));

   startTimer();

   quesNum = 0;
  ```

  }
- **QuestionsActivity.java:43**

  public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
- **QuestionsActivity.java:105**

  ```
                } setQuestion();
  ```

**full code -- relevent areas marked with ***** mark.**

```js
*********this is QuestionsActivity.java:43 line ********
public class QuestionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView question, qCount, timer;
    private Button option1, option2, option3, option4;
    private List<Question> questionList;
    private int quesNum;
    private CountDownTimer countDown;
    private int score;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private int setNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        qCount = findViewById(R.id.qcount);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        option1 = findViewById(R.id.optin_a_btn);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.optin_b_btn);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.optin_c_btn);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.optin_d_btn);

        option1.setOnClickListener(this);
        option2.setOnClickListener(this);
        option3.setOnClickListener(this);
        option4.setOnClickListener(this);

        questionList = new ArrayList<>();

        setNo = getIntent().getIntExtra("SETNO",1);

        //add below line
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        getQuestionList();

        score = 0;
    }


    private void getQuestionList() {

        questionList.clear();
        firestore.collection("QUIZ").document("CAT" + String.valueOf(category_id)).collection("SET" + String.valueOf(setNo))
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                Map<String, QueryDocumentSnapshot> questList = new ArrayMap<>();

                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    QuerySnapshot questions = task.getResult();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : questions){
                        questionList.add(new Question(doc.getString("QUESTION"),
                                doc.getString("A"),
                                doc.getString("B"),
                                doc.getString("C"),
                                doc.getString("D"),
                                Integer.valueOf(doc.getString("ANSWER"))
                                ));
                    } setQuestion();               *************105 line
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }

    private void setQuestion()
    {
        timer.setText(String.valueOf(40));

        question.setText(questionList.get(0).getQuestion());  *****151 line********
        option1.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionA());
        option2.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionB());
        option3.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionC());
        option4.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionD());

        qCount.setText(String.valueOf(1)+"/"+ String.valueOf(questionList.size()));

        startTimer();

        quesNum = 0;
    }

    private void startTimer()
    {
        countDown = new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                changeQuestion();

            }
        };
        countDown.start();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int selectedOption = 0;

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.optin_a_btn:
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.optin_b_btn:
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.optin_c_btn:
                selectedOption = 3;
                break;

            case R.id.optin_d_btn:
                selectedOption = 4;
                break;
            default:
        }

        countDown.cancel();
        checkAnswer(selectedOption, v);

    }

    //Remove tint list
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void checkAnswer(int selectedOption, View view)
    {
        if(selectedOption == questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns())
        {
            //Right ans
            ((Button)view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
            score++;
        }
        else
        {
            //Wrong ans
            ((Button)view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.YELLOW));
            switch (questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns())
            {
                case 1:
                    option1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
                    break;

                case 2:
                    option2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
                    break;

                case 3:
                    option3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    option4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
                    break;
            }
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeQuestion();
            }
        },500);

    }
    private void changeQuestion()
    {
        if( quesNum < questionList.size()- 1)
        {
            quesNum++;

            playAnim(question,0,0);
            playAnim(option1,0,1);
            playAnim(option2,0,2);
            playAnim(option3,0,3);
            playAnim(option4,0,4);

            qCount.setText(String.valueOf(quesNum+1)+"/" + String.valueOf(questionList.size()));

            timer.setText(String.valueOf(40));
            startTimer();

        }
        else
        {
            //score activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionsActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SCORE",String.valueOf(score) + "/" + String.valueOf(questionList.size()));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            //QuestionsActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
    private void playAnim(final View view, final int value, int viewNum)
    {
        view.animate().alpha(value).scaleX(value).scaleY(value).setDuration(500)
                .setStartDelay(100).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                        if (value == 0)
                        {
                            switch (viewNum)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    ((TextView)view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getQuestion());
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    ((Button)view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionA());
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    ((Button)view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionB());
                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    ((Button)view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionC());
                                    break;

                                case 4:
                                    ((Button)view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionD());
                                    break;
                            }

                            if (viewNum != 0)
                                ((Button)view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#023047")));

                            playAnim(view,1,viewNum);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        countDown.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems questionList variable is defined but it does not add any items before calling the setQuestion function(Line 151). This might happen if task.getResult() is empty on the line 96 or task.isSuccessful() is false in line 95. Try to debug those and you can find the root cause.

Comment: Thank u ayye....